# Grouping ActiveSupport::Timezone objects to one TimeZone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone, activesupport

I am wondering is it possible to make dropdown list that will group entries by TimeZones.

I am using rails 4, ActiveSupport::TimeZone, time_zone_select.

What i am trying to achieve is following:
Currently my time_zone_select contains

- (GMT-11:00) American Samoa
- (GMT-11:00) International Date Line West
- (GMT-11:00) Midway Island etc.

What i want to show:

- (GTM-11:00) American Samoa, International Date Line West, Midway
  Island
- etc.

Do I have to make my own object that will map these things or I can do some kind of GroupBy on ActiveSupport::TimeZone array.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would not be a good idea.  These are three different time zones, with three different definitions.  A time zone rule contains much more than just its current standard offset.  Please read "time zone != offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).  And while you're there, please read the section about Rails time zones as well.  Thanks.

Comment: Hi Mat,
Maybe I haven't explained really well what I meant to say. Lets say that I use IANA timezone database, and one entry is as follows:
RU
+5545+03735
Europe/Moscow
Moscow+00 - west Russia

Or another example: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_European_Time

So, in the end I may have duplicate values, but in my opinion it will be more user friendly and instead of 147 entries there will be 50-ish.

Thanks for your answer

Comment: After several problems with this I must agree with you. Thanks